# How can I search Stack Overflow with Stack.PHP?

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to search the Stack Overflow questions using the [php stacks app](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-powerful-and-extensive-library-for-accessing-the-stack-exchange-api)

But I can't seem to find the search method, I'm trying to pass a search string parameter to the method (if it exists)

For example:

```
$stackoverflow = API::Site('stackoverflow');

$searchString;

$response = $stackoverflow->???->Exec(); // problem here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Column 80 - Plain Text optimised SOFU](https://stackapps.com/q/542/10353) ([code](http://www.column80.com/Column80.zip)) has a search feature and is based on that library, too. So it's a working example and probably helpful.